# Greater Than Equal to

Tags: python

I am making a game of countdown (game show) And cant get it to work.

The Part that doesn't work is separated with a `-------`.

```
import random      # Import Module_1
import time        # Import Module_2

choice = 0

number = 0

z = input("How many Big Numbers?")
if int(z) == 1:
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))

elif int(z) == 2:
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))

elif int(z) == 3:
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))

elif int(z) == 4:
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))

elif int(z) == 5:
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))

elif int(z) == 6:
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))
    print (random.randrange(25,125,25))
```

---

```
x = input("How many Small Numbers")
if y == int(z) + int(x):
    if int(y) >= 7:
        if int(x) == 1:
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))

        elif int(x) == 2:
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))

        elif int(x) == 3:
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))

        elif int(x) == 4:
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))

        elif int(x) == 5:
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))

        elif int(x) == 6:
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))

else:
    print("That Doesn't Add up to 6 Numbers.")
```

Comment: I don't see any "-------". Besides "it doesn't work" doesn't mean much to us. What are you trying to do, what is the expected result and what is the real result?

Comment: i would like to make the program print a certain number of random numbers according to user input. The real result is it always saying "That doesnt Add up to 6 numbers"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Should do this with no if statement.

```
y = int(z) + int(x)
```

Notice you use an `=` to define `y`. The reason it goes straight to the else statement is because `y` is not defined.

The remaining lines would look like this if you really want to optimize

```
if int(y) >= 7:
    if int(x) <= 6:
        for i in range(x):
            print(random.randrange(0,11,1))
```

Comment: thanks a bunch mate, how could i be so stupid

Answer (score 0):

On line `if y == int(z) + int(x):` variable `y` is not defined. Note that `==` is comparison, not assignment (which is `=`). Also I believe you have to use `for` loop instead of copy-pasting one line to do something several times.

Comment: it gives me invalid syntax when i use one "="

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what do you want to do here. If you want to introduce new variable `y` and make it equal to `int(z)+int(x)`, why you use `if` here?

Comment: Seems OP doesn't understand. I'd say add the full code example would be better.